# Removing items from an array if another array have similar items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two arrays one is the main array wherein I have different parameters and another array which have only two parameters that matches from first array.

I want to remove the complete item from first array if similar array(matched on these two parameter) matches.

Eg:

```
var mainArray = [{'Name':'Ticket1','TaskId':'b5de781e-9d25-49e7-af6d-3e254e894c04','ResourceId':'977dacf0-0b61-413e-a9a4-b469ab30d1b1',
'Status':'Completed'},{'Name':'Ticket2','TaskId':'c5ae581e-9f25-49e7-af6d-3e254e894c04','ResourceId':'37fdadf1-0b61-413e-a9a4-b469ab30d1b1',
'Status':'InProgress'},{'Name':'Ticket3','TaskId':'45af551e-9f25-49e7-af6d-3e254e894c04','ResourceId':'37fdadf1-0b61-413e-a9a4-b469ab30d1b1',
'Status':'InProgress'}];

var tmpArray = [{'TaskId':'b5de781e-9d25-49e7-af6d-3e254e894c04','ResourceId':'977dacf0-0b61-413e-a9a4-b469ab30d1b1'},{'TaskId':'45af551e-9f25-49e7-af6d-3e254e894c04','ResourceId':'37fdadf1-0b61-413e-a9a4-b469ab30d1b1'}];
```

I want my final array to have items which are not in tmpArray with similar TaskId and ResourceId only.

i.e my final array should look like

```
[{'Name':'Ticket2','TaskId':'c5ae581e-9f25-49e7-af6d-3e254e894c04','ResourceId':'37fdadf1-0b61-413e-a9a4-b469ab30d1b1',
'Status':'InProgress'}]
```

Here the items are removed as they had matching TaskId and ResourceId in tmpArray

Comment: You can use `mainArray.splice(startIndex, endIndex)` to remove the items from the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) in combination with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/) should help.

```js
var mainArray = [{ 'Name': 'Ticket1', 'TaskId': 'b5de781e-9d25-49e7-af6d-3e254e894c04', 'ResourceId': '977dacf0-0b61-413e-a9a4-b469ab30d1b1', 'Status': 'Completed' }, { 'Name': 'Ticket2', 'TaskId': 'c5ae581e-9f25-49e7-af6d-3e254e894c04', 'ResourceId': '37fdadf1-0b61-413e-a9a4-b469ab30d1b1', 'Status': 'InProgress' }, { 'Name': 'Ticket3', 'TaskId': '45af551e-9f25-49e7-af6d-3e254e894c04', 'ResourceId': '37fdadf1-0b61-413e-a9a4-b469ab30d1b1', 'Status': 'InProgress' }],
    tmpArray = [{ 'TaskId': 'b5de781e-9d25-49e7-af6d-3e254e894c04', 'ResourceId': '977dacf0-0b61-413e-a9a4-b469ab30d1b1' }, { 'TaskId': '45af551e-9f25-49e7-af6d-3e254e894c04', 'ResourceId': '37fdadf1-0b61-413e-a9a4-b469ab30d1b1' }],
    result = mainArray.filter(function (a) {
        return !tmpArray.some(function (b) {
            return a.TaskId === b.TaskId && a.ResourceId === b.ResourceId;
        });
    });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Or a solution with better perfomance/complexity and a helper object

```js
var mainArray = [{ 'Name': 'Ticket1', 'TaskId': 'b5de781e-9d25-49e7-af6d-3e254e894c04', 'ResourceId': '977dacf0-0b61-413e-a9a4-b469ab30d1b1', 'Status': 'Completed' }, { 'Name': 'Ticket2', 'TaskId': 'c5ae581e-9f25-49e7-af6d-3e254e894c04', 'ResourceId': '37fdadf1-0b61-413e-a9a4-b469ab30d1b1', 'Status': 'InProgress' }, { 'Name': 'Ticket3', 'TaskId': '45af551e-9f25-49e7-af6d-3e254e894c04', 'ResourceId': '37fdadf1-0b61-413e-a9a4-b469ab30d1b1', 'Status': 'InProgress' }],
    tmpArray = [{ 'TaskId': 'b5de781e-9d25-49e7-af6d-3e254e894c04', 'ResourceId': '977dacf0-0b61-413e-a9a4-b469ab30d1b1' }, { 'TaskId': '45af551e-9f25-49e7-af6d-3e254e894c04', 'ResourceId': '37fdadf1-0b61-413e-a9a4-b469ab30d1b1' }],
    result = function (array1, array2) {
        var o = {};
        tmpArray.forEach(function (a) {
            o[a.TaskId + '|' + a.ResourceId] = true;
        });
        return mainArray.filter(function (a) {
            return !o[a.TaskId + '|' + a.ResourceId];
        });
    }(mainArray, tmpArray);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```